# RESTFUL Web Service - List

Tags: web-services, rest, arraylist, response

I have a client application requesting a list of channels from a webservice. Is it possible to take the "response" from the web service and store it in an ArrayList?

Meaning if I wanted to store a list of channels for example, it would normally come from the web service as a response, typically from ResponseBuilder.

And I want to store it in an ArrayList from the client, like List.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TypeReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) to instantiate your `Channel` object list, here is an example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;

public class ChannelClient {

  public void getChannels() {
    Response serviceResponse = client.target("http://your_service_url/channels/").
                request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Response.class);
    String responseString = serviceResponse.readEntity(String.class);
    List<Channel> list = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(new TypeReference<List<Channel>>() {
        }).readValue(responseString);
  }
}
```

Make sure to have `Jersey JSON Jackson` jar in your dependencies, you can get it from here

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson/2.26-b07

EDIT: In case you want to consume `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` response, you will just change the request method argument to your specified type like this:

```
 Response serviceResponse = client.target("http://your_service_url/channels/").
            request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(Response.class);
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to use the GenericType you're proposing:

RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type text/plain and type interface java.util.List

Comment: It's working; thank you for the help. I do, however, have one question.

If I'm trying to consume MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, as opposed to APPLICATION_JSON, how can the code slightly change?

Comment: @HaisamTarekElkewidy I updated my answer, please check it, also If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.